# How to Get an original cd of ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

Boa tarde, sou fã do ubuntu a muito tempo gostaria de conseguir um cd original e um manual de como instalar programas manualmente.
Abraços e parabéns pelo belo trabalho a cada versão lancada.

ENGLISH :
Good afternoon, I'm a fan of ubuntu a long time I would get an original cd and a manual on how to install programs manually.
Hugs and congratulations for the beautiful work every release.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah , actually there was a canonical program to ship Ubuntu CD's free around the world . But that program was closed . Now you have the only way is to download the Ubuntu ISO from its official site

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

The manuals(softcopy) you can get from Ubuntu Documentation

https://help.ubuntu.com/

for support on any information/problems/suggestions you can visit

[askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)
and [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org)

Comment: "Now...the only way is to download the Ubuntu ISO."You can BUY bulk packs  (5 disks) from Canonical - http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Comment: Or individual discs can be bought too.